# How to transfer C++ object to lua script using LuaBridge

Tags: luabridge

I want to integrate lua scripting language with my serialization library, in code like this:

```
void cSerializableLua::ThisToLua( lua_State* l, bool classDeclaration )
{
    if( classDeclaration )
    {
        getGlobalNamespace( l )
        .beginNamespace( "CLASS" )
            .beginClass<Property>( "Property" )
                .addProperty( "Number",   &Property::GetNumber, &Property::SetNumber )
                .addProperty( "String",   &Property::GetString, &Property::SetString )
                .addProperty( "Real"  ,   &Property::GetReal,   &Property::SetReal   )
            .endClass()
        .endNamespace();
    }

    for( iterator it = this->begin(); it != this->end(); ++it )
    {
        Property* iser = *it;

        std::string namespaceLUAName = iser->Path(false);
        std::string objectLUAName    = iser->Name();

        getGlobalNamespace( l )
        .beginNamespace( namespaceLUAName.c_str() )
            .addVariable( objectLUAName.c_str() , iser)
        .endNamespace();
    }

    for( cChildList::iterator it = this->ChildList()->begin(); it != this->ChildList()->end(); ++it )
    {
        cSerializableLua* iser = *it;
        if(iser) { iser->ThisToLua( l, false ); }
    }
}
```

It works almost perfect unfortunately LuaBridge, is creating copy of my "class Property" objects so every changes i make in script for example:

```
VSPThread.STADDR.String = "http://87.239.46.3/mjpg/video.mjpg"
VSPThread.WIDTH.Number = 640
VSPThread.HEIGHT.Number = 480
VSPThread.ENABLE.Number = 1
```

don't change my c++ lifetime objects.

My question is, how can i force LuaBridge to copy changed data back to my c++ objects?

Comment: This isn't a good fit for LuaBridge (or other automatic binding generators). Since your member list is dynamic, you'll want to directly implement the __index/__newindex metamethods.

Comment: My Property items are known at compile time so in fact they are not dynamic. How can I use __index/__newindex metamethods? i cant find any good example on internet :(